# Lego Mindstorms NXT 2.0 Not turning on

Tags: nxt, repair

I have a Lego Mindstorms NXT 2.0, which worked well for a couple of years.
However, after the last few weeks, it seems to not boot up. I took it apart, and noticed it seems to have a different internal design than the other ones. After screwing around with it for a bit, it unexpectedly boot up.

I thought the plastic part holding the ribbon cable in place was putting too much pressure on the cable, causing malfunction. After I reassembled it with less pressure on the screen mount, and sealed the unit back up, it seems to be dead, *again.*

Any help? I prefer not to solder.

Comment: Is the NXT not starting up *at all* (no startup sound, no USB, no screen), or just the screen is not turning on? I ask because ageing NXTs have historically had a lot of problems with screens ceasing to display anything, though the rest of the controller's functionality is not impaired.

Comment: Never mind, it's fixed. Turns out the battery terminal was not properly fitting the new batteries.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to know you figured it out. Lego no longer offers replacement NXTs so the only other course of action would be a third-party reseller such as Ebay or BrickLink.

Comment: @RuhiBatool .. feel free to add the solution as an answer to your own question - maybe others have similar problems...